# Payment Gateway for Reimbursing Customers More than Purchase Amount?

Tags: payment-gateway, stripe-payments, payment

I have a website where we offer a subscription service on a monthly basis (kind of like an insurance plan). I am using Stripe as a payment gateway for recurring payments because it is easy to use and user-friendly: just enter your credit card, name, and email, and you're done.

However, sometimes people file claims, and we have to reimburse them. But with Stripe, you can only refund the original amount, not more. What method or payment gateway can I use where we store the users' credit card info and can reimburse them any amount?

For example, the plan is $5 per month. If they file a claim, let's say we have to send them $50 to cover it. How can I accomplish this electronically without sending a check or something?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think that this kind of operation is supported for credit cards. I develop payment gateway and for credit cards there are only sale, preauth, postauth, void, return ... I think you should ask for IBAN + SWIFT during registration and when you need send any amount to customer, just use it.

Comment: Maybe paypal would be easier then?

Comment: Yes paypal could also solve your problem. I would suggest to implement most common payment method for your country (customer portfolio). There are payment gateways which supports many payment methods, for example https://www.firstdata.com/en_us/all-features/payeezy.html